# empty PrimitiveList is ignored by DynamoDB

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm saving user profiles in DynamoDB, and using attributes for converting the .net types to dynamo entries

so this is a converter that I'm using:

```
public class DictRoomClassHouseInfoConverter : IPropertyConverter
{
    ...

    public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
    {
        var dictionary = value as Dictionary<RoomClass, HouseInfo>;

        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type");
        }

        var entry = new PrimitiveList();

        foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
        {
            entry.Add(new Primitive { Value = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", (int)kvp.Key, kvp.Value.House, kvp.Value.TimesSold) });
        }

        return entry;
    }
}
```

now the problem is that when the Dictionary is empty and an empty `PrimitiveList` is returned by `ToEntry`, the changes for this Dictionary won't be saved

so if I do something like:

```
var profile = GetProfile(id);
//profile.DictProp has 3 items; 


profile.DictProp.Clear();
//profile.DictProp has 0 items;

SaveProfile(profile);

var p = GetProfile(id);
//profile.DictProp has 3 items;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@jtlebi answered correctly that the service does not accept empty strings or empty sets. The .NET SDK builds on this, in that if you try to save an empty PrimitiveList, the SDK will ignore this and the attribute will not change.

However, there is still a way to remove an attribute: set the field on the .NET object to null or return null from the IPropertyConverter.ToEntry method. Then, when you call DynamoDBContext.Save, the SDK will issue a DELETE command for that particular attribute.

Comment: tried returning null in the `public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry`, but it's the same as returning empty PrimitiveList, the attribute is not affected

Comment: @Chuck Norris, make sure you have the latest version of the SDK. This was a semi-recent addition.

Comment: using 1.4 updating to the latest, will let you know how it went

Comment: Thnx, updating to the latest (1.5.5.6) and returning null instead of empty PrimitiveList worked, although haven't tried if it works when returning empty instead of null

Answer (score 3):

DynamoDB will always return a `ValidationException` if you attempt to save an element with an empty attribute.

The only way to avoid this is to save save the item without this field.

This said, I don't know the .NET SDK but I'm surprised it does not handle this automatically ?

See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html for a list of DynamoDB tricky limitations.

Comment: by attribute do you mean .net attribute or something else, my dictionary property has attribute on it the [DictRoomClassHouseInfoConverter] attribute

Comment: I see, I suppose you're talking about this limitation: Attribute values - Attribute values cannot be null or empty.

Comment: I mean the attribute on DynamoDB side. I have no notion of .NET so it's a bit hard for me to help with this specific case.